# How to call dynamic collection in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to convert a string as a parameter into a collection model in nodejs?
So when someone visits example.com/?table=products, I want to access the products collection. How can I do that?

```
route.get("/products", async (req, res) => {

    var symbol = req.query.symbol;
    if (symbol == null) {
        res.json({ 'status': 'fail', 'msg': 'symbol not found' });
        return;
    }
    const sampleScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
        price : String
    }, {versionKey : false, strict: false});
    
    
   let model = await db.model(symbol, sampleScheme);
   var data = await model.find();
    return res.json({ 'status': 'success', 'data': data });
});
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, what is the issue in your current implementation?

Comment: Even though there is data in the table, empty value is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();

// Assuming 'db' is your MongoDB connection
// You need to set up your MongoDB connection before using this route

route.get("/products", async (req, res) => {
    const symbol = req.query.symbol;

    if (!symbol) {
        return res.json({ 'status': 'fail', 'msg': 'symbol not found' });
    }

    try {
        // Check if the collection exists in MongoDB
        const collectionExists = await mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({ name: symbol }).hasNext();

        if (!collectionExists) {
            return res.json({ 'status': 'fail', 'msg': 'collection not found' });
        }

        // Define schema for the dynamic model
        const sampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            price: String
        }, { versionKey: false, strict: false });

        // Create or retrieve the dynamic model
        let model = mongoose.models[symbol] || mongoose.model(symbol, sampleSchema);

        // Query the collection using the dynamic model
        const data = await model.find();

        return res.json({ 'status': 'success', 'data': data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({ 'status': 'error', 'msg': 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

module.exports = route;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I am getting the following error: MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Comment: mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase', {
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,  
    socketTimeoutMS: 45000,  
    // Other options...
}); try to increase